# How to implement at ending_ver in Dijkstra’s algorithm?

Tags: python

Currently im working on a project where I've been asked the following question, "Explain how the graph is an abstraction of the problem"
Could someone help to understand that concept please?

I also have the following piece of code which works  perfectly, but I want to modify it by  adding an ending_ver to return the shorttest path between the ver given

```
import heapq


def dijkstras(grh, str_ver):

    distances = {vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in grh}
    distances[str_ver] = 0
    
    pq = [(0, str_ver)]
    while len(pq) > 0:
        current_distance, current_vertex = heapq.heappop(pq)
        
        #noodes can get added to the priority q multiple times
        #we only process a vertex the first time we remove it from the priority Q
        
        if current_distance > distances[current_vertex]:
            continue
        
        for neighbor, weight in grh[current_vertex].items():
            distance = current_distance + weight
            
            #Only consider this new path if its better than any
            #path we've already found
            
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                heapq.heappush(pq, (distance, neighbor))
                
    return distances
```